# No available shapes in this compartment and availability domain

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm using the OCI San Jose region and I'm trying to create a capacity reservation in OCI under `Compute` -> `Capacity Reservation` but whenever I try to create a capacity reservation, the `Shape` dropdown list is greyed out with the message:

```
No available shapes in this compartment and availability domain
```

Does this mean that this region is at capacity and is not capable of reservations at this time?  Or is there a limit or restriction I'm not aware of?

I've been trying each day this week but the message remains the same.

Comment: Are you on free tier?  https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/reserve-capacity.htm#how_reserved_capacity_works__limitations

Comment: @Joe no, I'm not on the free tier.

Answer (score 1):

It does mean that for that specific shape, the region is at capacity and not capable of taking reservations. You can certainly file a support request to find the capacity situation.  This does seem to indicate that your use of reservations is sound practice.

You can also use the command line interface to check the region for available shapes:

`$ oci compute shape list`
or better
`$ oci compute shape list | jq -r .data[].shape | sort | uniq`